# How to package and the load resource files outside jar file

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, maven-assembly-plugin

I have following maven-standard project structure:

```
/project-root
|-- ui/
   |-- src/main/
      |-- java/*.java
      |-- resources/templates/*.ftl
|-- core/
   |-- src/main/
      |-- java/*.java
      |-- resources/
         |-- items/*.json
         |-- locations/*.json
         |-- scripts/*.js
         |-- *.properties
```

I would like to package it to something like:

```
/game
|-- assets/
   |-- templates/*.ftl
   |-- items/*.json
   |-- locations/*.json
   |-- scripts/*.js
   |-- *.properties
|-- executable-game.jar
```

I tried to use maven-assembly-plugin and maven-jar-plugin but without success.
Another problem is I don't know how to correctly load those files after packaging. Now I'm using this simplified snippet:

```
URL url = new Dummy().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filePath);
Path path = Paths.get(url.toURI());
```

but this code loads files from inside of the jar file.

Comment: your question is about packaging or loading file from jar?

Comment: You are using Spring Boot... Then why use the assembly plugin? Spring Boot already handles this. Use Spring to load the resources instead of trying to roll your own.

Comment: Does spring boot assembly plugin allows to package resources files outside of the jar file?